# Specify PORT environment variable on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, express, command-line-interface

In my settings I run my server on port 4000. I want to run it now on port 5000 in another instance. I have read here:

https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786

that all you need to do is something like:

```
PORT=5000 node server.js
```

Now, this is what I have in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "nodemon -e ts -w ./src -x npm run watch:serve",
    "watch2": "PORT=5000 yarn watch",
    "watch:serve": "ts-node --inspect src/index.ts",
}
```

I useally run "yarn watch" and my server runs on port 4000. yarn watch2 should make it run on port 5000 but I get the following error:

```
"'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command"
```

I assume it is because I am working on Windows?

What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The npm package [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) is an excellent solution to setting environment variables across different platforms. For example, you would use:

```
"scripts": {
  "watch2": "cross-env PORT=5000 yarn watch"
}
```